# Get first list index containing sub-string?

Tags: python, list

For lists, the method `list.index(x)` returns the index in the list of the first item whose value is `x`. But if I want to look inside the list items, and not just at the whole items, how do I make the most Pythoninc method for this?

For example, with

```
l = ['the cat ate the mouse',
     'the tiger ate the chicken',
     'the horse ate the straw']
```

this function would return `1` provided with the argument `tiger`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A non-slicky method:

```
def index_containing_substring(the_list, substring):
    for i, s in enumerate(the_list):
        if substring in s:
              return i
    return -1
```

Comment: Python is such a great language and has no builtin support for such things ? ️

Answer (score 39):

With a one-liner:

```
index = [idx for idx, s in enumerate(l) if 'tiger' in s][0]
```

Comment: It does not run if there are NA's. How to consider this case?

Answer (score 8):

Variation of abyx solution (optimised to stop when the match is found)

```
def first_substring(strings, substring):
    return next(i for i, string in enumerate(strings) if substring in string)
```

If you are pre 2.6 you'll need to put the `next()` at the end

```
def first_substring(strings, substring):
    return (i for i, string in enumerate(strings) if substring in string).next()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def find(l, s):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if l[i].find(s)!=-1:
            return i
    return None # Or -1
```

Answer (score 3):

This is quite slick and fairly efficient.

```
>>> def find(lst, predicate):
...     return (i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if predicate(j)).next()
... 
>>> l = ['the cat ate the mouse','the tiger ate the chicken','the horse ate the straw']
>>> find(l, lambda x: 'tiger' in x)
1
```

Only problem is that it will raise StopIteration if the item is not found (though that is easily remedied).

Comment: StopIteration can be avoided:
`return next((i for i,j in enumerate(lst) if predicate(j)), -1)`
(Python 2.6+)

Answer (score 2):

```
def first_substring(strings, substring):
    return min(i for i, string in enumerate(strings) if substring in string)
```

Note: This will raise `ValueError` in case no match is found, which is better in my opinion.

Comment: Fancy but not efficient, as it tests all elements of the list regardless of whether the text has been found previously or not.

Also, Python's 'something'.find(s) function returns -1 when no match is found, so I'd call that Pythonic.

Comment: Does not work, at least in Python 2.6. You can't use both an iterable and an extra argument in `min()`. @Etiene: this is a generator expression, not a list comprehension, so it wouldn't generate everything.

Comment: @Etienne - premature optimization is the root of all evil etc.
@Max - you are correct, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

imho with this line, you'll find only the first occurence without processing the whole list

`index = next((i for i in enumerate(l) if "tiger" in i[1]),[-1,-1])[0]`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to just get the text and not raise exception if item was not found

```py
search = 'a'
next((s for s in ["aa",'c'] if search in s), None)

search = 'b'
next((el for el in ["aa",'c'] if search in el), None)
```

It's one of those things I wish was just implemented natively.

Answer (score 0):

```
  >>> li = ['my','array','with','words']
  >>> reduce(lambda tup, word: (tup[0], True) if not tup[1] and word  == 'my' else (tup[0]+1 if not tup[1] else tup[0], tup[1]), li, (0, False))[0]
  0
  >>> reduce(lambda tup, word: (tup[0], True) if not tup[1] and word  == 'words' else (tup[0]+1 if not tup[1] else tup[0], tup[1]), li, (0, False))[0]
  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map function:

```py
index = np.nonzero(map(lambda x: substring in x, strings))[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

@kennytm offers a great answer that helped me; to build from theirs a function that allows regex, I wrote:

```
def substringindex(inputlist, inputsubstring):
    s = [x for x in inputlist if re.search(inputsubstring, x)]

    if s != []:
        return (inputlist.index(s[0]), s[0])
    return -1
```

This function works exactly like theirs, but supports regex.