# Return an index of a string stored in an array

Tags: python

I have an array and an input, if I input something I want to use `.startswith()` with my array, for example if I have this:

```
Array = ['foo','bar']
```

And if I input `"fo"` I want it to match it with `"foo"` and then return the index, in this case `0`. How would I do this?

Comment: Do you mean `a = ['foo', 'bar']` or is `foo` a variable there...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170900/get-first-list-index-containing-sub-string-in-python for how to find a substring. Then just change the substring match to `startswith()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution. I iterated through the list and for each item checked if they start with the string `'fo'` (or whatever your want to check with). If it starts with that string it prints the index of that item. I hope this helps!

```
Array = ['foo', 'bar']

for item in Array:
    if item.startswith('fo'):
        print(Array.index(item))
```

Comment: Thankyou, I had to make a few minor adjustments but it is working!

Comment: Glad I could help, if my answer worked be sure to check it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: It was a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: Great, looks good. I would note that it doesn't work with repetitions, but that's probably fine as long as OP didn't specify he neesd them

Comment: I looked at your answer and it looks great. Gave it an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

MaryPython's answer is generally fine. Alternatively, in O(n) instead of O(n^2), you could use

```
for index, item in enumerate(my_list):
       if item.startswith('fo'):
            print(index)
```

I've used [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-enumerate.html) to walk the index with the item

Note that Marky's implementation fails on this array

```
 ['fo','fo','fobar','fobar','hi']
```

because `.index` always returns the [first instance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) of a repeated occurrence (but otherwise his solution is fine and intuitive)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: ascii -*-

Data = ['bleem', 'flargh', 'foo', 'bar' 'beep']

def array_startswith(search, array):
    """Search an iterable object in order to find the index of the first
    .startswith(search) match of the items."""
    for index, item in enumerate(array):
        if item.startswith(search):
            return(index)
    raise(KeyError)
    ## Give some sort of error. You probably want to raise an error rather
    ##     than returning None, as this might cause a logic error in the
    ##     later program. I think KeyError is correct, based on the question.
    ## See Effective Python by Brett Slatkin, Page 29...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lookfor='fo'
    try:
        result=array_startswith(lookfor, Data)
    except KeyError as e:
        print("'{0}' not found in Data, Sorry...".format(lookfor))
    else:
        print("Index where '{0}' is found is: {1}. Found:{2}".format(lookfor, 
            result, Data[result]))
    finally:
        print("Try/Except/Else/Finally Cleanup happens here...")
    print("Program done.")
```

Comment: Wow, that seems like a lot more hassle than needed. Take a look at en_Knight's or my answer, much less code but still gets the job done.

Comment: I was going for a more "batteries included" answer, giving as complete an answer as I could.

Comment: According to "The Zen of Python" (type `import this` into the python shell to see), "Simple is better than complex.".