# return pandas dataframe column with substrings of another column

Tags: string, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like df and I want to add a column so it looks like df2.

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.DataFrame({'Alternative' : ['a_x_17MAR2016_Collectedran30dom', 'b_17MAR2016_CollectedStuff', 'c_z_k_17MAR2016_Collectedan3dom'], 'Values': [34, 65, 7]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Alternative' : ['a_x_17MAR2016_Collectedran30dom', 'b_17MAR2016_CollectedStuff', 'c_z_k_17MAR2016_Collectedan3dom'], 'Values': [34, 65, 7], 'Alts': ['a x 17MAR2016', 'b 17MAR2016', 'c z k 17MAR2016']})

    df
Out[4]: 
                       Alternative  Values
0  a_x_17MAR2016_Collectedran30dom      34
1       b_17MAR2016_CollectedStuff      65
2  c_z_k_17MAR2016_Collectedan3dom       7

df2
Out[5]: 
                       Alternative             Alts  Values
0  a_x_17MAR2016_Collectedran30dom    a x 17MAR2016      34
1       b_17MAR2016_CollectedStuff      b 17MAR2016      65
2  c_z_k_17MAR2016_Collectedan3dom  c z k 17MAR2016       7
```

In other words I have a string that I can separate with an underscore delimeter that is of varying length.  I want to separate it, then combine it delimeted by a space, but remove any string(s) after starting with the string containing the substring 'Collected'.

I can locate the index of the string containing the substring 'Collected' in an individual list as I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170900/get-first-list-index-containing-sub-string-in-python) and then combine the other strings, but I cannot seem to do it in a very 'pythonic' way across all of the dataframe.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this would technically answer the question but not match the desired output as the date does not contain the word 'Collected'

```
df.Alternative.str.replace('_[^_]*Collected.*', '').str.replace('_', ' ')
```

Output

```
0      a x 17MAR2016
1        b 17MAR2016
2    c z k 17MAR2016
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I feel this answers the question and uses pandas without the need to import re.  I appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

use
`str.split`

```
alts = df.Alternative.str.split('_').str[:-1].str.join(' ')
df.insert(1, 'Alts', alts)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x = df.Alternative.apply(lambda x : re.sub("_Collected.*","",x))
# x
#0      a_x_17MAR2016
#1        b_17MAR2016
#2    c_z_k_17MAR2016

y = x.str.split("_")
#0       [a, x, 17MAR2016]
#1          [b, 17MAR2016]
#2    [c, z, k, 17MAR2016] 

df['newcol'] = y.apply(lambda z: ' '.join(z))
#                       Alternative  Values           newcol
#0  a_x_17MAR2016_Collectedran30dom      34    a x 17MAR2016
#1       b_17MAR2016_CollectedStuff      65      b 17MAR2016
#2  c_z_k_17MAR2016_Collectedan3dom       7  c z k 17MAR2016
```

all in one line :

```
import re
df['newcol'] = df.Alternative.apply(lambda x : re.sub("_Collected.*","",x)).str.split("_").apply(lambda z: ' '.join(z))

#                       Alternative  Values           newcol
#0  a_x_17MAR2016_Collectedran30dom      34    a x 17MAR2016
#1       b_17MAR2016_CollectedStuff      65      b 17MAR2016
#2  c_z_k_17MAR2016_Collectedan3dom       7  c z k 17MAR2016
```

Comment: This doesn't specifically search for the string 'Collected'

Comment: but to get the expected output as you shared, you might not need to search for Collected right?

Comment: Yes, your output matches the output desired from Jeff Tilton but it doesn't answer his question. My answer answers his question but doesn't match his output. He needs to clarify things a bit.

Comment: This isn't my question but your solution still has problems when you the word 'Collected' does not immediately follow an underscore.