# Python: Trying to find indices of a substring in a 2D list

Tags: python

I essentially altered this code:

```
def index_containing_substring(the_list, substring):
    for i, s in enumerate(the_list):
        if substring in s:
              return i
    return -1
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170900/get-first-list-index-containing-sub-string-in-python)

And made it into this:

```
def index_containing_substring(the_list, substring):
    for (x,y), s in enumerate(the_list):
        if substring in s:
              return (x,y)
    return -1
```

And got this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I tried casting my list to a string using str(list), however this did not solve the problem, and I did not expect it to since my list consists of strings anyway...

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I see the code, and I understand the error. But that's probably because I've been coding python for a really long time. To help me understand your issue better, what output did you expect from your script?

Comment: What are you expecting `(x, y)` to be?

Comment: I wanted them to be the index values of my 2d list

Comment: `the_list` is a one-dimensional list. What 2d list are you referring to?

Comment: I made a 2D list from a csv file. When I call the function, I use my 2D list as the_list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `the_list` is a 2D list, use a double for loop:

```
for x, sublist in enumerate(the_list):
    for y, s in enumerate(sublist):
        if substring in s:
            return (x, y)
```

(note that as written, `x` will iterate over rows and `y` will iterate over columns; be careful about which order you expect!)

Comment: I got this error:

    for x, sublist in the_list:
    ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Sorry, you need to call enumerate on the lists. Edited.

Comment: Hey this worked before, but now i am getting this error:

    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Have you changed the input (the value of the_list)?